# The unit sphere is not bijective

Tags: general-topology, analysis, algebraic-topology, banach-spaces

Let $S^n = \{ x \in \mathbb R^n : ||x|| = 1 \}$ be the unit sphere, then there exists no bijection between $S^n$ and an open subset of any Banach space.

How to show that?

I see that $S^n$ could not be homeomorphic to any Banach space, as $S^n$ is compact, and any Banach space is not compact as for example the sequence $\{ n\cdot u \}$ for any $u \ne 0, u \in E$ does not has a limit. But for the more general notion of bijectivity I do not see it...

Comment: You really want bijection here?

Comment: Yes, the original question looked for a plain bijective map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true, the cardinal of $S^1$ is $R$ since $S^1$- one point is $R$, so there exists a bijection between $S^1$ and $R$ and $R$ is a Banach space.

Comment: I suspected that, but it is an exercise; anyway quite easy to give a bijection between $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R \cup \{ x \}$ for $x \notin \mathbb R$, choose some countable subset of $\mathbb R$ and shift everything to make room for the additional point.

Comment: Can you elaborate by what you mean by $S^1$-one point is $R$. Do you mean there exists a bijective function that takes  $S^1\setminus \{x\} \to \mathbb{R}$ where $x\in S^1$, and if so, can you refer me to a proof of this or suggestion on how to prove it?

Comment: @LoveTooNap29: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection